# How to specify return value of chainlink MockOracle

Tags: oracles, chainlink, mock

I want to test my smart contract locally using [chainlink MockOracle](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-mix/blob/main/contracts/test/MockOracle.sol)  how can i specify the returned value and the job Id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to test your contract locally with mockOracle, there is no Chainlink node participating in the process.

In local test, you deploy the mockOracle and functions in the mockOracle are called by yourself rather than Chainlink off-chain node(which in the real use case). In the scenario, you do not need real jobId because you are not requesting a specific job of a chainlink node to return a value.

Please check the unit test of apiConsumer in [hardhat-starter-kit](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit/blob/main/test/unit/APIConsumer.spec.js), there are several unit tests in the test file.